# ": bad variable name read: website"

Tags: server, bash, scripts, apache2, lamp

So I'm trying to make a .sh script for my Ubuntu LAMP server that makes it easier to add a new website to apache2, but when I try executing I get the error

```
: bad variable name read: website
```

I've done some searching and can't find the answers I need and there are several spots through my script where lines that match the same setup as the line causing the error are made. Here's the setup on the line I think is causing the error

```
read -p 'What is the website title (no spaces): ' website
```

Here's the entire script:

```
echo Starting website builder
read -p 'What is the website title (no spaces): ' website
echo Website title saved as $website
echo creating storage folder
mkdir -p /var/www/$website
echo changing file permissions
chown -R $name:$name /var/www/$website
chmod -R 755 /var/www/$website
echo creating test file
echo <html> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
echo <head> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
echo    <title>Success</title> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
echo </head> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
echo <body> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
echo    <h1>$website is operational</h1> >> var/www/$website/index.html
echo </body> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
echo </html> >> /var/www/$website/index.html
clear
cat /var/www/$website/index.html
echo
read -p "press [Enter] to continue"
clear
echo creating $website.conf file
echo <VirtualHost *:80> >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
read -p 'Enter ServerName: ' ServerName
echo        ServerName $ServerName >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
read -p 'Enter ServerAlias (domain name): ' ServerAlias
echo        ServerAlias $ServerAlias >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
read -p 'Enter ServerAdmin: ' ServerAdmin
echo        ServerAdmin $ServerAdmin >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
echo        DocumentRoot var/www/$website >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
echo        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
echo        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
echo </VirtualHost>
clear
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/$website.conf
echo 
read -p "press [Enter] to continue"
clear
echo activating website
a2ensite $website
service apache2 restart
echo Open a web browser on any pc and visit $ServerAlias. If you have errors make sure the alias and external ip was properly set up on the domainservice you signed up with.
read -p 'Process completed. Press [Enter] to end.'
clear
```

Comment: Your script lacks a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/372691/301745) about removing/replacing Windows line endings.

Comment: On an unrelated matter, you'll need to quote echoed strings like `echo <html>` to `echo "<html>"` or `echo '<html>'` to prevent interpretation of `<` and `>` by the shell. Or better, learn how to use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what could cause a script to fail to find python when it has \`#!/usr/bin/env python\` in the first line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372672/what-could-cause-a-script-to-fail-to-find-python-when-it-has-usr-bin-env-pyt)

Comment: @wjandrea Just that *the underlying problem* and therefore the solution is the same doesn’t make *the question* a duplicate IMO – one could think about closing this as a duplicate of a general question about problems arising from line endings (not sure whether we have one), but certainly not link a question asking about a `read` error with a question about a `python` shebang.

Comment: @dessert True. There isn't really a general question about line endings, so most questions I've seen get closed as duplicates of the one I linked. Maybe we should make a general question.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your off topic comment because it helped me figure out why nothing was showing in my test index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrambled error message points to an issue with Windows line endings. You can convert the line endings in the file to linefeeds (Unix format) with:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' /path/to/your/script
```

or (you may need to install [`dos2unix` [image: Install dos2unix]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dos2unix) first):

```
dos2unix /path/to/your/script
```

Further reading:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/372691/507051
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33320706